# Translation of terms in views?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I have a view that returns a group of terms (these terms are translated and they appear on the website on both languages correctly) that doesn't show the translated words when i try to view the view.

View structure:

```
TITLE
Title:Themes

FORMAT
Format:JSON data document | Settings

FIELDS
Taxonomy term: Term ID (TermID)
Taxonomy term: Name (TermName)


FILTER CRITERIA
Taxonomy vocabulary: Machine name (in , ...)

SORT CRITERIA
```

I get the same json for both languages instead of 2 seprate words for the 2 urls: website/en/      website/otherlanguage/

```
{
    "Themes": [
        {
            "TermID": "119",
            "TermName": "Digital Strategy"
        },
        {
            "TermID": "563",
            "TermName": "Entrepreneurship"
        },
        {
            "TermID": "562",
            "TermName": "Innovation"
        },
        {
            "TermID": "561",
            "TermName": "Innovation Management"
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Entity Translation? If so, you can add a relationship to the view.

```
'Content:Entity translation: translations'
```

When adding the fields, there should now be fields that look like this:

```
'Entity translation:YOUR-FIELD-NAME: translated'
```

Once these are added, the fields will automatically use the translated content based on which language the user has selected.